# How much a scene would be done in 3D modelling program before exporting?

Tags: models, level-design, 3dsmax, assets, maya

What I am trying to work out is, when creating a level, or section of a level, how much is created in the modeling package before it is exported, take the scene in the link. Would this whole scene be created in Max first, if so what is the point of a level editor, where does that come into play.

Basically how are levels made, how much of a whole level, or section of a level is created in the modeling software, how can multiple people work on the same level at once, what is the relationship of a level editor to modeling package like 3ds max?

**I would be using Unreal 4 and 3ds Max.**

[image]

Comment: This depends on the game. Although, typically in a lot of engines (like Unity) you simply model individual objects and compose them as a scene inside the level editor.

Comment: Say for Unreal 4, what would your likely software and approach be, I assume you would use say 3ds first... Any chance of as detailed a breakdown as possible all the steps?

Comment: I would edit the question if you have a specific engine in mind

Comment: I just said Unreal 4 + say 3ds Max.

Comment: What you said is a comment, he said edit the question.